# Removing the selected option from dropdown and then adding a new selected value does not highlight the option using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to select the option value on the basis of the data fetched using AJAX.

This works for the first time but could not run after removing the option and then re-adding it.

```
$("#branch option:selected").removeAttr('selected');
   $.each(joblocation_array, function(i,val) {
   $('#branch option[value="'+val+'"]' ).attr("selected", true);
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have :

```
<select id="mySelect" multiple>
    <option value="aaa">aaa</option>
    <option value="bbb">bbb</option>
    <option value="ccc">ccc</option>
    <option value="ddd">ddd</option>
    <option value="eee">eee</option>
</select>
```

to set multiple options :

```
var values = ['aaa', 'ccc'];
$("#mySelect").val(values);
```

to add options to those currently selected :

```
var values = ['ddd', 'eee'];
var currentSelection = $("#mySelect").val();
$("#mySelect").val(currentSelection.concat(values));
```

to deselect an option :

```
var value = 'eee';
var currentSelection = $("#mySelect").val();
var index = currentSelection.indexOf(val)
if(index > -1) {
    currentSelection.splice(index, 1);
}
$("#mySelect").val(currentSelection);
```

to deselect multiple options :

```
var values = ['aaa', 'eee'];
var currentSelection = $("#mySelect").val();
for(var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
    var index = currentSelection.indexOf(values[i])
    if(index > -1) {
        currentSelection.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
$("#mySelect").val(currentSelection);
```

**[DEMO1](https://jsfiddle.net/b4od2f5q/2/)**

**[DEMO2](https://jsfiddle.net/b4od2f5q/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

The right way to change selected option with jQuery is to use `.val()` function.

From [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

> `val()` allows you to pass an array of element values. This is useful
>   when working on a jQuery object containing elements like `<input
>   type="checkbox">`, `<input type="radio">`, and `<option>`s inside of a
>   `<select>`. In this case, the inputs and the options having a value that
>   matches one of the elements of the array will be checked or selected
>   while those having a value that doesn't match one of the elements of
>   the array will be unchecked or unselected, depending on the type. In
>   the case of `<input type="radio">`s that are part of a radio group and
>   `<select>`s, any previously selected element will be deselected.

So, to select a single option:

```
$("#myselect").val(*value*);
```

To select many options (with multiple select), you have to pass an array of values:

```
$("#myselect").val([val1,val2]);
```

See following example, please:

```js
$("#btnAction").click(function(){
  $("#test").val(["2","4"]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="test" multiple="multiple">
  <option id="opt1" value="1" selected="selected">One</option>
  <option id="opt2" value="2">Two</option>
  <option id="opt3" value="3">Three</option>
  <option id="opt4" value="4">Four</option>
  <option id="opt5" value="5">Five</option>
</select>
<button id="btnAction">Select 2 and 4</button>
```

I hope it helps you, bye.

Comment: Thanks ,but this is only to select single option what about selecting multiple option in dropdown

Comment: When you start the example, option "one" is selected, after click on the button, select "one" will deselected and only 2 and 4 will selected.